# Transport kitchen stand mixer from China to Europe by plane

Tags: transportation, airport-security, electronic-items

I'm an Italian living in China. I've bought a kitchen stand mixer in Italy and used here in China.

When I moved here it was packed into a container and delivered by sea.

Now I want to bring it back to my home in Italy, this time by plane with me, as a checked baggage.

Are there any restrictions for electrical devices such as this?

Will there be any tax to pay?

[image]

Comment: If you bought it in Italy, did you pay Italian VAT when you bought it in the first place? That might be grounds to avoid duty when you reimport it.

Comment: And both because I'm personally curious and because it is potentially relevant to answering questions about how to transport it, what kind of "kitchen robot" are we talking about here?

Comment: @ZachLipton duty is different than VAT.

Comment: Are you referring to a Thermomix? If so, it has carry bags designed for travel with dimensions of 40.6 x 34.6 x 7.4 cm. The steel blades would have to be in checked baggage, of course.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the object as packed, and what is the weight?

Comment: Guys, guys, "robot" simply means "mixer".

Answer (score 2):

Answer is of course, yes.  It's totally OK to check items like TVs, microwaves, appliances, when you fly. You see people doing this every time.

I believe you should NOT have to pay tax.  It would be good if you had the receipt that you originally bought it in Italy, but, my guess if you could "talk your way" from it.  After all, it will not look brand new.

Nothing to worry about.